# Hide a lot of divs while mouseover

Tags: javascript, css

When the mouse is over the 'main' div, I want it to hide all the 'mCenter' divs.

How can I do this **without** jQuery? (with JS or CSS)

It's not a problem for me to do the id's unique, and after that to run on all the id's. But there is no better way to do what I need?

```
echo "<div id='main'>";     // main div
for ($i=1; $i<100; $i++) {
     echo "<div id='mem.$i' style='width:100%; padding:3px; padding-bottom:0px; cursor:hand;' onmouseover=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#1d1d1d';\" onmouseout=\"this.style.backgroundColor='Transparent';\">
               <div id='mRight' style='float:right;'> right </div>
               <div id='mCenter' style='float:right;'> center (divs to hide) </div>
               <div id='mLeft'> left </div>
          </div><br>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: The id attribute should be unique.

Comment: @Wex its not problem for me to do the id's unique, and after that to run on all the id's. but there is no better way to do what i need?

Comment: The mRight, mCenter, mLeft, you could just do it as classes. Just my opinion though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a css rule. You need to make one that will target the children divs (id=mCenter) of the parent div, (id=main). You need to use a pseudo selector (`:hover`) so that your rule will only apply when the main div id hovered.

This rule will do the trick:

```css
#main:hover #mCenter
{
    display: none;
}
```

*Note*: the fact that this works doesn't imply that its valid html if you include more than 1 element with any given id.

Answer (score 0):

Add rule to style file:

```
#main:hover #mCenter{display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#main:hover #mCenter
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**#main is main div id id

**#mCenter is you want hide div id

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript Solution:**

```
    var content = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
    content += "<div style='width:100%; padding:3px; padding-bottom:0px; cursor:hand;'><div style='float:right;'> right </div><div class='mCenter' style='float:right;'> center (divs to hide) </div> <div> left </div></div><br/>";
    }
    var el = document.getElementById("main");
    el.innerHTML = content;

    el.onmouseover=function(){    
     var hidediv = document.getElementsByClassName("mCenter");
     for(var k = 0; k < hidediv.length; k++){
        hidediv[k].style.display = 'none';
     }
    };

    el.onmouseout=function(){    
     var hidediv = document.getElementsByClassName("mCenter");
     for(var k = 0; k < hidediv.length; k++){
      hidediv[k].style.display = 'block';
     }
    };
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nba89/88/)

**CSS Solution:**

You can use [`Pseudo-classes selector`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) to track [`hover`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) event.

Tr it:

```
#main:hover .mCenter
{
    display: none;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nba89/87/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the below option, as I am not sure wether it's id or class.
if mCenter is class

```
#main:hover div.mCenter { display:none; }
```

or if mCenter is id

```
#main:hover div#mCenter { display:none; }
```

or it's a immediate child

```
#main:hover > div { display:none; }
```